# Show processing status at each step of PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a form that uploads a file, then performs a series of steps to output several files to the user. Each of these steps can take some time and I would like to display which step of the process is currently happening in real-time, using javascript. I prefer not to use ob_flush and flush in PHP to handle this.

Here is my example code:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
    //Step1 -- upload file and import into database
    echo "Working on step 1...<br>";
    for ($x = 0; $x <= 5; $x++) { sleep(1); }

    //Step2 -- compare imported date to reference table, create new temp table
    echo "Working on step 2...<br>";
    for ($x = 0; $x <= 5; $x++) { sleep(1); }

    //Step3 -- create 3 different files from reference table
    echo "Working on step 3...<br>";
    for ($x = 0; $x <= 5; $x++) { sleep(1); }

    //Complete
    echo "Complete!";
    die();
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#myForm').submit(function() {
            $('#loaderImg').show();
            return true;
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <form action="" method="post" id="myForm" name="myForm" onsubmit="myButton.disabled = true; return true;">
            <input type="submit" id="clicknow" name="myButton" value="Submit"><br>
            <img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/500/1*em5HcTFZIQw90qIgdbYjVg.gif" alt="loader1" style="display:none; height:400px; width:auto;" id="loaderImg">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't have a lot of javascript knowledge so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have the AJAX tag? You're not using AJAX to sunmit the form.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate as that thread doesn't apply to what I'm trying to accomplish

Comment: What's the difference? You want to send incremental output to the browser, that's what it does.

Comment: This has nothing to do with JavaScript, you're just doing ordinary form submission.

Comment: The difference is using flush doesn't always work depending on Apache server configurations that have certain modules enabled, like mod_gzip, unless I'm mistaken. The point is I wanted to try to handle this with JavaScript, but if that's not possible, that's fine. Question answered I guess.

Comment: It's the only simple way to do it. If you want something more general, you'll need to use WebSockets.

Comment: Sounds good. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Have a second PHP file that watches the files and use JavaScript to communicate with the second file. WebSockets or long polling with the Fetch API should work. However, I am afraid an answer would be beyond the scope of an StackOverflow answer.